# Find the set $A$ such $x,y\in A,1<x<y,$,then $xy-2\in A$

Tags: number-theory

Assmue that the set $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},\cdots\}$ if $a_{i}$ are odd numbers,such

（1）： $n\ge 3$

(2):if the $a\in A$,then the divisor of $a$ also in $A$

(3):if $x,y\in A,1<x<y,$,then $xy-2\in A$

Find $A$

by $(2)$ it is clear $1\in A$

Comment: Are there $n$ elements in $A$, or infinitely many?

Comment: @Arthur  infinitely many

Comment: Then why care about $a_n$ and $n\geq 3$? I guess just to make certain we don't just set $A = \{1\}$ or $A = \{1, 3\}$, or something like that?

Comment: @Arthur,Yes that's problem mean

Comment: Could you expand on how it's clear that $3\in A$, because to me that's not entirely obvious.

Comment: Why not simply take $A = \mathbb{Z}$? Do you have conditions on the set to find, or are you just supposed to give any set fulfilling the conditions?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold First off, it's specified that all numbers in the set are odd. Second, from context I would assume that all the $a_i$ are positive. Lastly, I _think_ the problem asks us to prove that $A$ is necessarily the set of all odd naturals. There are a lot of assumptions here, but it is the least amount of assumptions that makes this problem both solvable and non-trivial (at least that I can see).

Comment: Oh,I found the $3$ is not clear,sorry